# How can I create a recursive menu in HTML / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take a look at the image below:

[image]

I want to create a menu like this but I don't know how to start. Any thoughts?

Comment: accordion menu it is.

Comment: Looks like accordion

Comment: try with accordion or tree

Comment: it is also an accordion too, as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, in fact. It consists in a recursive nodelist.

You can achieve that by using `ul`, `li` and `a` simultaneously:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Text here</a>
    <!-- repeat -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

And to perform the behavior, it's pretty simple too. You must see if the `a` element has a `nextElementSibling`, and if it has, it's because the current node has a child.

Take a look at the example below I created:

```js
(function() {
  var tree = document.getElementById('tree');

  /* firstly, we hide all the child items */
  [].forEach.call(tree.querySelectorAll('ul li a'), function(el, i) {
    if (el.nextElementSibling)
      el.nextElementSibling.classList.add('hidden');
  });

  /* here we make a event delegation, we add an event handler to the hole tree */
  tree.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.target;

    /* if the element clicked is an anchor, it's because it's a node/leaf */
    if (el.tagName === 'A') {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      /* if it has a nextElementSibling, it's because it has children, so it's a node */
      if (el.nextElementSibling) {
        /* we toggle the visibility of the child */
        el.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
      } else {
        // do something with the final child (leaf)
        console.log(el.textContent);
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Father</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Son</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Grandfather</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Father</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a>Son</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Father</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Son</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```